# Firefox 11 3D Dom viewer not available

Tags: firefox, web-development

I've got Firefox 11 running in Windows 7, and the 3D DOM viewer doesn't appear for me; it's not an option in the Developer Tools.  I know where to look, because I've used it on another computer under OS X.  Do I have to change a setting somewhere to enable it?

EDIT: The solution ended up being updated graphics drivers.  I'm on a 17" MacBook Pro with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[3D View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Tools/Page_Inspector/3D_view) requires [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL). Your graphics card may be [blacklisted](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Blocklisting/Blocked_Graphics_Drivers) by Firefox or your graphics card drivers are outdated. If updating your drivers does not resolve the issue, you can [force-enable](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Blocklisting/Blocked_Graphics_Drivers#How_to_force-enable_blocked_graphics_features) **unsupported** features by setting the following preferences under [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config):

- WebGL - `webgl.force-enabled` = `true`
- WebGL anti-aliasing - `webgl.msaa-force` = `true`
- Layers Acceleration - `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` = `true`
- Direct2D Content Acceleration - `gfx.direct2d.force-enabled` = `true`

Comment: I set these to true and restarted Firefox and I still don't have the 3D DOM option.

Comment: Then, your graphics card is likely not compatible.

Comment: I went and updated my graphics drivers and restarted Firefox, and it worked.

Comment: I see. I assumed you already tried updating your drivers, as I mentioned in my answer! :)